# В чём отличие слабой типизации от сильной?

Tags: c

В чём отличие слабой типизации от сильной ?
И почему язык Си слабо типизирован?

Comment: Я не виду нигде более иди менее строгого определения этих видов типизации языка.

Answer (score 7):

Строгая\Не строгая типизация определяет то, может ли язык неявно преобразовать данные различных типов.

---

Си/C++:

```
int a = 2;
char b = 'L';
int c = a + b;
```

Да, да, вам не показалось. Мы сложили число и символ (!) и получили новое число.

Как это работает? Си неявно преобразовал символ `'L'` в число — а именно в номер, который соответствует этому символу в таблице кодировок ASCII. Номер, соответствующий символу `'L'` в этой таблице — `76`. Таким образом, в `c` у нас окажется значение `2+76=78`

Си/С++ - это языки с Не строгой типизацией.

---

Python:

```
a = 2
b = 'L'
c = a + b # Здесь будет ошибка
```

Python не позволяет нам складывать такие две разные сущности как «целое число» и «символ».

Python - язык со строгой типизацией.

Таким образом, языки со строгой типизацией не позволяют смешивать сущности разных типов в выражениях и не выполняют никаких автоматических преобразований, а языки не строгой типизацией, наоборот всячески способствуют, чтобы программист смешивал разные типы в одном выражении.

---

Источник: [pikabu - Поймут не только программисты (надеюсь)](https://pikabu.ru/story/poymut_ne_tolko_programmistyi_nadeyus_5370728).

Comment: Уииии, уже с Пикабу ответы берём :)

Comment: "Си неявно преобразовал символ 'L' в число " - это неправда. В языке С `'L'` - это сразу именно число.

Answer (score 1):

Сильная / слабая типизация (также иногда говорят строгая / нестрогая). Сильная типизация выделяется тем, что язык не позволяет смешивать в выражениях различные типы и не выполняет автоматические неявные преобразования, например нельзя вычесть из строки множество. Языки со слабой типизацией выполняют множество неявных преобразований автоматически, даже если может произойти потеря точности или преобразование неоднозначно.

Примеры:
Сильная: Java, Python, Haskell, Lisp;
Слабая: C, JavaScript, Visual Basic, PHP.